# Left join on 2 varchar fields not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im having trouble joining two varchar(31) fields on sql server 2008. below is my query and it works fine

```
select A.CustId,A.Country,B.Country from [ACC].[dbo].[Customer] as A
left join 
[Task Centre].[dbo].[CountryCodes] as B on A.Country=B.Country]
```

the results are as follows

```
CustomerA    United Kingdom    Null
CustomerB    Ireland           Ireland
CustomerC    Spain             Spain
CustomerD    South Africa      Null
```

South Africa and United Kingdom don't match even though they are in both dbs

I have tried to replace the space but its very slow and doesnt work. I think its something to do with the whitespace but I cant find the right command to achieve what I want.

Bear with me if I have omitted anything as Im a novice, I have also searched everywhere for an answer but cant find one that works for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Mike

Comment: @TomTom: Did it occur to you that OP might not be in charge of the database design? Maybe he just got assigned a task of querying some data from a legacy database application, and now he needs a little help with the query... If you have nothing productive to add to the question, then don't say anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to execute the following query on both tables. This will tell you if there's any "hidden" difference between the tables (for example, blank characters, line breaks, etc.):

```
select Country, CAST(Country AS VARBINARY) AS BinaryCountry
from [ACC].[dbo].[Customer]
where Country = 'United Kingdom'

select Country, CAST(Country AS VARBINARY) AS BinaryCountry
from [Task Centre].[dbo].[CountryCodes]
where Country = 'United Kingdom'
```

The column `BinaryCountry` should show a different value, if the content of the `Country`-columns are not exactly the same. If that is the case, consider correcting the error in either table. Once you've made sure that the value is the same in both tables, your join should work just fine.

Edit: The problem turns out to be a non-breaking space character in the Task Centre-table. To workaround this, use the following in your join criteria:

```
ON A.Country = Replace(B.Country, CHAR(0xA0), ' ')
```

Comment: Hey dan, I think this may be the answer the result from the acc db is United Kingdom
0x556E69746564204B696E67646F6D
and the MMD task centre db is blank. I'm a little lost as to what this means? thanks

Comment: Well, apparently the string `'United Kingdom'` does not exist in your Task Centre table. Could you identify the record with UK in some other way instead of `where Country = 'United Kingdom'`?

Comment: Sorry Dan its in capitals in the other db the result is 0x554E49544544A04B494E47444F4D
UNITED KINGDOM

Comment: Okay, so apparently, your database is set to a case sensitive collation. Use this in your join: `UPPER(A.Country) = UPPER(B.Country)`

Comment: Hi Dan, I tried that and the single words join but double barrel like United Kingdom still dont

Comment: Okay - the difference is that one of your tables uses the hex character 20 as a space (regular space), whereas the other table uses A0 (non-breaking space). You will have to manually account for this. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Awesome dan that worked perfectly and Ill have the VARBINARY piece for when I run into something similar.... Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

If any space is in value you need to trim and check

```
SELECT A.CustId, A.Country, B.Country
FROM   [ACC].[dbo].[Customer] AS A LEFT JOIN
       [Task Centre].[dbo].[CountryCodes] AS B 
             ON LTRIM(RTRIM(A.Country)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(B.Country))
```

Comment: By default, SQL Server ignores trailing spaces, which means you could shorten the JOIN criteria to `LTRIM(A.Country) = LTRIM(B.Country)`

Comment: I tried this previously but it didnt work, it think there is difference between the two fields Im comparing. Dans answer above may be the solution to my specific problem

Answer (score 0):

If the difference is whitespace, then I guess this might work for you.  It will be slow though, since it won't be able to use any indexes:

```
select  A.CustId,
        A.Country,
        B.Country 
from
(
    SELECT  A.CustId,
            A.Country,
            LOWER(REPLACE(A.Country, ' ', '')) AS CleanedCountry
    FROM    [ACC].[dbo].[Customer] as A
) A
left 
join 
(
    SELECT  B.Country,
            LOWER(REPLACE(B.Country, ' ', '')) AS CleanedCountry
    FROM    [Task Centre].[dbo].[CountryCodes] as B
) B
    on A.CleanedCountry=B.CleanedCountry
```

You would only need the lower if your collation is case sensitive...